# 4 crystal balls and a 10,000 story building

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

There is an analog of this question I've heard with 2 crystal balls but a higher number like 4 or more makes it much more interesting. You are given 4 crystal balls and there is a 10,000 story building. You are guaranteed that a crystal ball will break if dropped from a certain floor $m$ of the building or higher, otherwise it will not break when it is dropped from a floor lower than $m$. What is the minimum number of times you need to drop a ball in order to guarantee you can determine $m$ by the time all the crystal balls break?

As a bonus question, can an explicit formula for the maximum number of floors of the building be determined so that the problem can be solved with $k$ balls and $d$ drops, as a function of $k$ and $d$? I believe the answer should be a polynomial in $d$ of degree $k$.

Comment: It would seem that any strategy would have to end (on the last ball) with: increment ball drops from the last known safe height until the final ball breaks on floor $m$.

Comment: And for the first k-1 balls, a binary search would seem best. So for the specific case given, use the first 3 balls to get a range of 1250 floors, then test them with the last ball, giving 1253 as the maximum (or maybe 1252).

Comment: @rogerl:  the strategy below will do $10,000$ floors with four balls in $23$ drops

Comment: @rogerl The problem is asymmetric, so a binary search will be suboptimal.

Answer (score 4):

With $k=1$, you have to drop the ball from each floor as you go up, so the most floors you can handle with $d$ drops is $d$  When $k=2$, you can afford to start at floor $d$, as if it breaks you can use the other ball $d-1$ times.  If it doesn't break, we have the problem with two balls and $d-1$ drops.  If $N(d)$ is the number of floors we can handle with two balls and $d$ drops, we get a recurrence $N(d)=(d-1)+1+N(d-1)$  We can compute some small values and discover $N(d)=\frac 12d(d+1)$, the triangular numbers.

For more balls, the same idea applies.  If we let $F(k,d)$ be the number of floors we can handle with $k$ balls and $d$ drops, the recurrence is $F(k,d)=F(k-1,d-1)+1+F(k,d-1)$  because you drop the first ball from floor $F(k-1,d-1)+1$.  You are correct that you get a polynomial in $d$ of degree $k$.  For four balls, I just put the recurrence into Excel, found trendline as a polynomial of degree $4$ and get $F(4,d)=\frac 1{24}d^4-\frac 1{12}d^3+\frac {11}{24}d^2+\frac 7{12}d=\frac 1{24}d(d+1)(d^2-3d+14)$

Comment: Does that equal ${d\choose 4}+{d\choose 3}+{d\choose 2}+d$?

Comment: @Michael:  According to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E4-2x%5E3%2B11x%5E2%2B14x%29%2F24-%28x+choose4%29-%28x+choose+3%29-%28x+choose+2%29-x) it does.  That makes a nice general conjecture.  Even nicer to write the last term $d \choose 1$

Answer (score 2):

The maximum is ${d\choose 4}+{d\choose 3}+{d\choose 2}+{d\choose 1}$.

You need to deduce the correct floor from the pattern of crashes - which of the $d$ drops caused balls to crash?  There were $4,3,2$ or $1$ crashes, which can happen in ${d\choose 4}+{d\choose 3}+{d\choose 2}+{d\choose 1}$ ways.  You can't have no crashes because then you still haven't found the ball's limit.

Ross Millikan shows how to achieve this limit.